# Using a Generic Class as a type parameter in another generic class

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I'm trying to create a list of properties in an interface like so: (just using 1 property for the example)

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
}
```

But I want to be able to create Implementations of this with different implementations of `IEnumerable<T>`. So for example, I want to be able to implement `IRepository` and have 'Budgets' as a list, or a `DbSet` (or any other custom class i make that implements `IEnumerable<T>`)

I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    // Database
    T<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
}
```

or

```
public interface IRepository<T>
where T : IEnumerable<>
{
    // Database
    T<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
}
```

Then I could implement it like so:

```
public class Repository : IRepository<List>
{
    List<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
}
```

but its not valid syntax.

Is this even possible and if not what alternatives do I possibly have?

Comment: Just curious: Why would you want this?

Comment: Hey Luke check out the "Repository" pattern, it's exactly what you want!

Comment: You may specify `T Budgets { get; }` on generic interface `IRepository<T> where T : IEnumerable<Budget>`. But to what purpose.. The interface could be non-generic exposing `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Bas The main reason i want to do this is because I want to implement multiple 'Repository' like classes all with the same types of properties (eg. Budget) but with different implementations of IEnumerable. If I made it simply IEnumerable<Budget> Then all my implementations would be IEnumerable and i'd have to do casts to get the List or DBSet (or whatever) Which i'd rather not do.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to support `Budget` then you had it very close with 2nd example

```
public interface IRepository<T>
where T : IEnumerable<Budget>
{
    // Database
    T Budgets { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to support more than just `Budget` as the inner type you need to use two generic types

```
public interface IRepository<T, U>
where T : IEnumerable<U>
{
    // Database
    T Budgets { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works for the given example, but gets messy when adding more properties, and flat out won't work for large amounts of properties

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a solution where I don't need to supply 'U' in the second example? As, in my model its likely that the properties will increase to like a dozen and upwards and i'd like them to be fixed and not generic, its just the type of IEnumerable (T in your example) that i want to change

Comment: @LukeBourne This is starting to smell like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I'm not really sure what you're trying to do is actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to be able to create Implementations of this with different implementations of IEnumerable.

That's exactly what your code already allows.

```
public interface IRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Budget> Budgets { get; set; }
}
```

Various implementations of this interface can return different implementations of `IEnumerable<Budget>`.

Here's a way to approach it. If a class is going to depend on a repository, write the interface from the perspective of the class that will depend on it. That way the class isn't just taking whatever interface is available. It "owns" the interface. It says what it needs.

The final, concrete implementation is dictated by technical decisions. You might have a back-end that returns a `DBSet<Budget>`. In that case that's what the concrete implementation will return.

Finally, write an adapter. It implements the interface required by the consumer. It calls the concrete repository and returns whatever it is that the consumer needs.

It sounds like more code (and it is) but here's what you accomplish.

- Your application logic is decoupled from the concrete implementation of the repository.
- You'll only write the code that you need. Instead of writing numerous alternate versions of the concrete repository, you'll only write an adapter when you need it. So compared to the initial approach it will be less code.

Comment: Thanks, This was the solution I was trying to avoid but it may be that i'm trying to do something that's either not possible, over-complicated or both. So just to clarify, if I want a `class ListRepository` that represents each property as a list and a `class DBSetRepository` that represents each property as a DBSet, are you saying i should create 2 separate interfaces? or keep to my 1 interface and create an adapter that returns the implementation I want?

Answer (score 0):

This example works for me. You can supply a type argument for any `IEnumerable` that can be populated from an array.

It's a little tricky to construct a concrete `IEnumerable` and populate it, since `IEnumerable` lacks any methods for adding to the collection, but I got around it by using a constructor that takes an array. Many of the types have it. 
 My example executes two tests, using a `List<Budget>` and a `ConcurrentQueue<Budget>`, and works fine.

I don't know how you possibly plan to use this thing to generate types of `IEnumerable` that don't have a constructor that takes an array.  For example, if you wanted `Dictionary<Budget>`, how would the factory (which runs only generic code) possibly know how to populate the keys? Seems like somewhere along the line you're going to need some non-generic code for that.

```
public class Budget
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IEnumerable<Budget>, new()
{

    T Budgets { get; }
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IEnumerable<Budget>, new() 
{
    public T Budgets
    {
        get
        {
            Budget[] data = GetData();
            var c = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new [] {typeof(Budget[])});
            object o = c.Invoke(new object[] { data });

            return o as T;
        }
    }

    private Budget[] GetData()
    {
        var a = new Budget[2];
        a[0] = new Budget { Name = "Hello world!" };
        a[1] = new Budget { Name = "Goodbye world!" };

        return a;
    }
}

class Example
{
    static public void TestList()
    {

        Repository<List<Budget>> r = new Repository<List<Budget>>();
        var list = r.Budgets;

        foreach (var b in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", b.Name));
        }
    }
    static public void TestQueue()
    {

        Repository<ConcurrentQueue<Budget>> r = new Repository<ConcurrentQueue<Budget>>();
        var list = r.Budgets;

        foreach (var b in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", b.Name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How would this work if I had 10-20 different properties in the interface though?

Comment: You add them? I don't see the problem.  Which interface?

Comment: When you instantiate your `Repository<List<Budget>>` You have to specifiy the property itself, so if i had 2 other properties in `IRepository`: `Wallet` and `Cash` the only way to do it using your method would be something like: `Repository<List<Budget>,List<Wallet>,List<Cash>>`. If i have twenty properties then thats not feasable.

Comment: I see. Perhaps use a generic method instead of a generic interface, e.g. instead of `Budgets` why not `GetBudgets<List<Budget>>()`.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to be able to get the same data but in a variety of data structures, may I suggest you use a bit of inversion of control and have the caller inject the structure?  That way he could supply his own custom data structure as well.

For example:

```
public void GetBudgets<T>(T collection) where T : ICollection<Budget>
{
    Db.GetBudgetData().ToList().ForEach(a => collection.Add(a));
}
```

Which you would call with:

```
var r = new Repository();
var list = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<Budget>(); //Or any ICollection
r.GetBudgets(list);  //Type is inferred, so no need for <HashSet<Budget>>
```

Or:

```
var r = new Repository();
var list = new CustomCollection<Budget>(); 
r.GetBudgets(list);
```

As a convenience to the caller, you can also supply a generic method that does not require an injection, so the caller can use a shorter piece of code when a custom collection is not needed:

```
public T GetBudgets<T>() where T : ICollection<Budget>, new()
{
    T collection = new T();
    GetBudgets(collection);
    return collection;
}
```

Which can be called with one line:

```
var budgets = repository.GetBudgets<List<Budget>>();
```

Using this approach makes it very easy for the caller. They would no longer have to instantiate a new `Repository<T>` for each different data type they want to work with; they just need to call the method. And you no longer have to figure out how to implement `IRepository<T>`, thus avoiding the problem entirely.

If you need to support a data type other than a descendent of `ICollection`, you will need a separate method, because the data layout is so different (e.g. a DataTable has columns, you need to pick what goes where) that generic code is not possible (`Add` is not universally available for all `IEnumerable` types). But you don't need a separate class, you can just use a [prototype overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx).